# How to pass a group of commands to a shell script in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that takes a group of commands on the command line (similar to how you can do with the "time" command), have it execute that group of commands and then based on the error code returned do something (if your curious, I'm having it call back to a speech daemon on my desktop to echo back the command and if it failed or succeeded - using this for some long running build processes)

With the unix time command if I have a list of commands I can run

```
> time (do_build && deploy_build)
```

With my command (which i call `tellme`) when I try this I get

```
> tellme (do_build && deploy_build)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do_build'
```

It doesn't seem to like the group of commands as parameters even though the exact same thing works fine for the time command.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the part of your script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you'll have to do something like

```
tellme 'do_build && deploy_build'
```

And inside tellme

```
eval "$*"
```

Answer (score 1):

`time` is actually executing its `(do_build && deploy_build)` parameter and waiting for it.

```
$ time (sleep 1; echo hello world;);
mundo

real    0m1.098s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.000s

$ echo asd (sleep 1; echo hello world;);
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

$ (sleep 1; echo hello world;);
mundo
```

You can't use subshells wherever you want.

In your case you need to use something like

```
$ (sleep 1; echo hello world) && tellme && echo done;
```

Comment: Good info on the subshells.  The proposed solution didn't accomplish what I needed as I wanted the tellme command to know the commandline being run so it can echo it back to me (in case I have several jobs running I'll know which one finished).

Comment: @Andrew well, then doing what you want without modifying `tellme` it's impossible. You must make `tellme` to accept parameters to either execute commands (like time, for example `tellme '(sleep 1; echo hello world)'` and run $1 from `tellme`) or accept a message parameter, like `(sleep 1; echo hello world); tellme 'hello world finished!'`

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
tellme "$(do_build && deploy_build)"
```

time is a bash builtin, if you use /usr/bin/time instead of time, you will see the same issue you have.